How to check entities values in left join list using Hibernate and JPQL
I need to select only DocEntity where all entities of “notificationEntityList” do not have “type”="NEW_DOCUMENT". My test example “selectTest()” works incorrectly, my example works the following way:

notificationEntityList b = {b.type=NEW_DOCUMENT, b.type=DOCUMENT, b.type=OLD_DOCUMENT }

this should no be selected because b.type has  type “b.type=NEW_DOCUMENT”, but it is selected, or when:

notificationEntityList b = {b.type=DOCUMENT, b.type=OLD_DOCUMENT }

this should be selected.
    public List<DocEntity> selectTest() {

        return em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM DocEntity a " +
                        "LEFT JOIN a.notificationEntityList b " +
                        "WHERE (NOT b.type =:notificationType  ) " +
                        "ORDER BY a.registrationDate DESC", DocEntity.class)
                .setParameter("notificationType", "NEW_DOCUMENT")
                .getResultList();


    } 


My NotificationEntity:
package lv.vda.luis_web.messager.entity;
import lv.vda.luis_web.document.entity.DocEntity;


import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;



@Entity
@Table(name = "Notification")
public class NotificationEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "`Notification_ID`")
    private Integer id;



    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "`Notification_type`")
    private String type;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "`Notification_docID`")
    private DocEntity docEntity;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public @NotNull String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(@NotNull String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public @NotNull DocEntity getDocEntity() {
        return docEntity;
    }

    public void setDocEntity(@NotNull DocEntity docEntity) {
        this.docEntity = docEntity;
    }

    /*CONSTRUCTORS*/
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        NotificationEntity that = (NotificationEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }



}


maybe a 'NEWDOCUMENT = all elements(a.notificationEntityList)' can give the same result and also let you remove the distinct on root entity; if 'all elements()' doesn't work i'll try with a exists/subselect
